# Create subscription plans via API

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

Is there a way to create new plans programmatically? Our users plans are dynamic and not fixed i.e users define their own amount for various items, and predefined plans won't cut it

Comment: Hi, I've noticed you've asked a few Flutterwave questions. If you've resolved these issues yourself, and the answers would be useful to others,you can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Flutterwave has an endpoint that enables you to create a plan without visiting that dashboard.

```
curl --request POST \
--url https://ravesandboxapi.flutterwave.com/v2/gpx/paymentplans/create \
--header 'content-type: application/json'
--data '{"amount":100, "name":"Monthly Debit", "interval":"monthly", "duration":"12", 
"seckey":"FLWSECK-xxxxxxxx-X"}'
```

Read more from the [Flutterwave Documentation](https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference#testinput)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the [tokenisation](https://developer.flutterwave.com/reference#save-a-card) feature offered by Rave by Flutterwave. This allows you control the plan, and billing cycle for a card by running your own cron job, it gives you as a dev full autonomy.

When you charge your subscribers card successfully the first time you get a token returned that you can use for subsequent charges.

Hope this helps, cheers mate.